# Force $.each() loop to wait for animations to complete before continuing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a delay between news items scrolling. I understand that $.each() is doing its job by not waiting for animations to finish, but I'd like to know how to make it so one item is scrolled up at a time and waits until the last animation has finished before continuing in the loop.

```js
$(function() {
  var parentHeight = $("#news_updates").height();
  $(".updateItem").css("top", parentHeight);
    
 
  $("#news_updates").children().each(function() {
    scrollr($(this));
  }); 
  
  function scrollr(itemToScroll) {  
    itemToScroll.animate({top: '40%'}, 3000).delay(7000).animate({top: -35}, 3000);
  }
});
```

```css
body 
{
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
#sponsor_updates {

}
#news_updates
{
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
#sponsor_updates h2 
{
  color: white;
}
.updateItem 
{
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sponsor_updates">
 <h2>News & Updates</h2>
 <div id="news_updates">
    <div class="updateItem">
      <p>News Item 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="updateItem">
      <p>News Item 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="updateItem">
      <p>News Item 3</p>
    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rather simple approach to delay and transition on page load, than once every 5 secs. It is what I use when it is not complicated like a slide where timing is consistent. It is faking it but works well for simple solutions.

```
var duration = 5000;

$('className').each(function(n) {
    $(this).delay(n * duration).fadeIn().delay(duration).fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to happen it will need to recurse on animation completion. Note that the delay was dropped to 700 for the sake of this demo.

```js
$(function() {
  var parentHeight = $("#news_updates").height();
  $(".updateItem").css("top", parentHeight);
    
 
  //collect items for recursion
  var items = $("#news_updates").children();
  
  //immediately call a named function to recurse with
  //break out when items are no longer present
  (function scrollr(items,index) {
    var itemToScroll = items.eq(index++);
    if(!itemToScroll.length)return;  
    itemToScroll.animate({top: '40%'}, 3000).delay(700).animate({top: -35}, 3000,function(){ scrollr(items,index); })
  })(items,0)
});
```

```css
body 
{
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
#sponsor_updates {

}
#news_updates
{
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
#sponsor_updates h2 
{
  color: white;
}
.updateItem 
{
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sponsor_updates">
 <h2>News & Updates</h2>
 <div id="news_updates">
    <div class="updateItem">
      <p>News Item 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="updateItem">
      <p>News Item 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="updateItem">
      <p>News Item 3</p>
    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```